# ssl implementation in jsp

Tags: jsp, netbeans, ssl

how to implement ssl (https) on localhost in java/jsp using tomcat server and Netbeans IDE. I don't have about the implementation of ssl. Please help me.!!

Sites, which i've visited

[SSL in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)